# Replace values in a PySpark Dataframe group with max row values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have this PySpark Dataframe:

```
+---+--------+-----------+
| id|language|    summary|
+---+--------+-----------+
|  2|    Java|      Great|
|  4|  Python|    Awesome|
|  7|  Python|    Amazing|
|  9|  Python| Incredible|
|  3|   Scala|       Good|
|  6|   Scala|  Fantastic|
+---+--------+-----------+
```

This issue is a bit convoluted, so please bear with me. For rows with the same language column value I want to be able to adjust the summary column values using the id as a tie breaker (the rows with the same language should select the row with the max id for that language and change all summaries to equal the max id row's summary). So for example for Python, I want to be able to replace all the summaries with "Incredible" since the row with "Incredible" has the highest id for Python. Same for Scala. So it would result into this:

```
+---+--------+-----------+
| id|language|    summary|
+---+--------+-----------+
|  2|    Java|      Great|
|  4|  Python| Incredible|
|  7|  Python| Incredible|
|  9|  Python| Incredible|
|  3|   Scala|  Fantastic|
|  6|   Scala|  Fantastic|
+---+--------+-----------+
```

We can assume that the ids are always going to be unique for each language group. We will never have the same id twice for one language although we may see the same id for different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the summary corresponding to the maximum id for each language using a window function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'summary', 
    F.max(F.struct('id', 'summary')).over(Window.partitionBy('language'))['summary']
)

df2.show()
+---+--------+----------+
| id|language|   summary|
+---+--------+----------+
|  5|   Scala| Fantastic|
|  6|   Scala| Fantastic|
|  2|  Python|Incredible|
|  3|  Python|Incredible|
|  4|  Python|Incredible|
|  1|    Java|     Great|
+---+--------+----------+
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I do have one follow up. Let's say we have an additional column like summary1 and we wanted to do the same to that column, how would I alter the code you gave me above to apply this to two columns each with their respective column values? Would it just be replicating the code again and just swapping out summary for summary1 or can we do it in one line?

Answer (score 2):

Another way using windowing:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.orderBy('language','id')

win = Window().partitionBy('language')
df = df.withColumn('summary', F.last('summary').over(win))
```