# PySpark most recent value replaces all other values in group

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have the following PySpark Dataframe:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|year|language_1| summary_1|language_2|summary_2|
+----+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|2013|      Java|     Great|    Python| Briliant|
|2014|    Python|   Awesome|     Scala| Horrible|
|2015|    Python|   Amazing|      Java|      Wow|
|2016|    Python|Incredible|       C++|     Nice|
|2017|     Scala|      Good|       C++|    Noway|
|2018|     Scala| Fantastic|       C++|     Cool|
+----+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

This issue is a bit difficult to explain, so please bear with me. For all the same languages in both langauges_1 and languages_2 I want to be able to adjust the summary_1 and summary_2 column values using the "year" column as a tie breaker, so the same language should select the row with the max year for that language and change all summaries in both summary_1 and summary_2 to equal the max year row's summary). So for example for Python, I want to be able to replace all the summaries with "Incredible" since the row with "Incredible" has the most recent year for Python. So on and so forth. So it would result into this:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|year|language_1| summary_1|language_2| summary_2|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|2013|      Java|       Wow|    Python|Incredible|
|2014|    Python|Incredible|     Scala| Fantastic|
|2015|    Python|Incredible|      Java|       Wow|
|2016|    Python|Incredible|       C++|      Cool|
|2017|     Scala| Fantastic|       C++|      Cool|
|2018|     Scala| Fantastic|       C++|      Cool|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can first melt the dataframe so that there are only 3 columns (year, language, summary), use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242501) for your previous question, and pivot the dataframe to restore the original structure:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'year', 
    'posexplode(array(struct(language_1 as language, summary_1 as summary), struct(language_2 as language, summary_2 as summary)))'
).select(
    'year', 'pos', 'col.*'
).withColumn(
    'summary', 
    F.max(F.struct('year', 'summary')).over(Window.partitionBy('language'))['summary']
).groupBy('year').pivot('pos').agg(
    F.first(F.struct('language', 'summary'))
).select(
    'year', '0.*', '1.*'
).toDF(*df.columns).orderBy('year')

df2.show()
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|year|language_1| summary_1|language_2| summary_2|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|2013|      Java|       Wow|    Python|Incredible|
|2014|    Python|Incredible|     Scala| Fantastic|
|2015|    Python|Incredible|      Java|       Wow|
|2016|    Python|Incredible|       C++|      Cool|
|2017|     Scala| Fantastic|       C++|      Cool|
|2018|     Scala| Fantastic|       C++|      Cool|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```